# Convert UTC to GMT -5 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i need convert a date field in UTC to GMT-5, this is my query;

```
Select 
A1.NAME23,
TO_CHAR(A1.TIME_END,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')TIME_END,
A1.VAR43 
From table
```

i trying this

```
select  to_char(cast(A1.TIME_END at time zone 'GMT-5' as date ),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as GMT-5 from table
```

but dont work

any suggestions

thanks.

Comment: Please state precisely what you mean by "but dont work".  Please give sample data and tell us what you got and what you expected to get.

Comment: this       from_tz(CAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A1.TIME_END,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')  at time zone 'GMT'   = 01-OCT-15 12.03.02.000000 AM GMT  and need the format "2015/10/01  12:03:02"

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a DATE datatype, then it's simply:

```
select time_end - 5/24 from table
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be this one:

```
A1.TIME_END at time zone '-05:00'
```